# How to replace '/' in a string with nospace?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to replace a string that contains `/` with no space.

Example :

Input: 'Test / Ignore';
Output: 'TestIgnore';

I know how to do other characters using `str.replace(/ |-/g, '');`, but I am  not able to implement this `str.replace(/ |//g,'');`

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You need to escape the `/` character as it has a special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the slash, and put it at the beginning of the regex, like so:

```
str.replace(/ \/|-/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.replace(/\/ | \s*/g,"")`.